# Referencing a constructor without resetting parameter values?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, object

Just for reference, I've taken like one high school class on Java, so this question should be super easy to respond to. I'm just having trouble figuring out a way to call a class method, the constructor, as a new object without putting in new values for the parameters. The constructor looks like this:

```
    public Skills(int courage, int intelligence, int stamina, int crafting, 
    int blacksmithery, int herbalism, int slingSkill, 
    int bowSkill, int swordSkill, int armor, int stealth, int 
    lifeForceSkill){
        this.courage = courage;
        this.intelligence = intelligence;
        this.stamina = stamina;
        this.crafting = crafting;
        this.blacksmithery = blacksmithery;
        this.herbalism = herbalism;
        this.slingSkill = slingSkill;
        this.bowSkill = bowSkill;
        this.swordSkill = swordSkill;
        this.armor = armor;
        this.stealth = stealth;
        this.lifeForceSkill = lifeForceSkill;
}
```

And when I establish it it my main method I do this:

```
    Skills skills = new Skills(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

To set all the levels to 1 and then I have the object skills to work with later. (Am I getting the terms constructors and objects mixed up? If it's wrong just switch them all in your mind I think I'm being consistent with it at least).

The problem is I have a toString() method in the Skills class that I want to call in a separate method in the main class.

```
    else if (optionChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("View Skills")){
        Skills skills = new Skills();
        System.out.println(skills.toString());
        break;
    }
```

Of course the object I create here throws an error because I cannot just write Skills(); without putting in all twelve values for the parameter. So how do I call the method from the Skills class when I can't create an object for it? It's imperative to functionality that the values do not change, and since they are variable and change with the program, I can't put any value in for them.

I know it's probably a super basic question but that's the level I'm at so any super basic answers would be helpful. Shouldn't take too much of your time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be better at stackoverflow since it's more implementation level.  Question, are you intending to create a new `Skills` object just to do a `toString()` on?  If you make changes to the on you created in the beginning, you won't see them even if you were to fix your compile error.  Also, `System.out.println(skills)` works just as well since `println()` can take an `Object`.  For an `Object` it automatically calls `toString()`.

Comment: May be useful: https://study.com/academy/lesson/static-vs-non-static-methods-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make your skills object a static field instead of creating it within the main method?

```
public class WhateverYourClassIsCalled {
    static Skills skills = new Skills(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }

    void yourOtherMethod() {
        // ...
        else if (optionChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("View Skills")) {
            System.out.println(skills.toString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could avoid static globals by passing the method what it needs: yourOtherMethod(skills);